# How to write binary file in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to write binary data to a file and add that as an email attachment.

```
  MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  NSData *data = [[self.samples componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/octet-stream" fileName:filename];
```

`addAttachmentData` expects an `NSData *` to be passed (although I'd prefer a byte array).  samples is an `NSMutableArray *`.  I'm getting extra formatting in the file that I do NOT want however, like angle brackets and whitespace:

```
...
<17700000 16c0f710 c78a2660 1570f960 c78926>
<17710060 17d0f800 c98826d0 2160f990 cb8d26>
...
```

Where are these coming from?  How can I truly write just binary data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calm down. NSData *is* a byte array — no more, no less. What you're seeing is just a figment of what the logging process does. Try this:

```
NSArray <NSString*>* arr = @[@"Mannie", @"Moe", @"Jack"];
NSData *data = 
    [[arr componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

The console outputs:

```
<4d616e6e 69650a4d 6f650a4a 61636b>
```

It's just NSLog making things neater. The bytes are just the 2-digit hex number values; there are no angle brackets and spaces in the data.

If you really don't believe me, print it this way:

```
char buffer[100];
[data getBytes:buffer length:data.length];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%02x", buffer[i]);
}
```

The output is just the character bytes:

```
4d
61
6e
6e
69
65
0a
4d
6f
65
0a
4a
61
63
6b
```

Comment: Wow you have an incredible reputation matt.  Hmm, I'm reading the sent attachment as a binary file in python and am seeing 0x3C = 60 = '<' as the initial byte.  When I open the file in sublime, I see the same thing.

Comment: Okay, but now you've sort of changed the question, haven't you? It seemed to me that question was "What are these extra things in my NSData?" And I showed you how to prove to yourself there are no extra things. How an octet stream is represented in an email is another matter.